# unable to download OpenCv on mac with pycharm

Tags: python, opencv

Don't know what the issue is. I am unable to download openCv on my mac with pycharm.

I use Python Version 3.8.1.

I have tried to:

`pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

`pip3 install --upgrade pip`

I use command:

`pip3 install opencv-python`

Still does not work. I get the message:

`ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python`

`Failed to build opencv-python`

What is the issue? Hope you can help. Has been taking me several of hours now and each time to "build" takes like 1 hour..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a MacBook with M1 processor?

The problem is that `pip` does not always install the arm64 version and instead tries to use rosetta to run amd64 versions which breaks. So it “works” it is just finicky and error prone.

Try to install following the steps on this blog: https://blog.roboflow.com/m1-opencv/

Comment: Don't know if I have M1 processor. I have an old macbook pro from 2012 :)

Comment: @GAUSS you don't have an M1 processor. This is not the issue.

Comment: Then not, since the M1 is the processor of the generation previous of the current one. But still try to install it using `conda-forge`.

Comment: I am completely lost and frustrated. I use Pycharm, if that make any difference. I have read a bunch of older posts in Stackoverflow also, but nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried what it says in the blog I attached?